# Unit test for aws lambda using jest

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, aws-lambda, jestjs

```
const invokeApi = require("/opt/nodejs/kiwiCall");
const decrypt = require("/opt/nodejs/encryption");
const cors = require("/opt/nodejs/cors");
```

When I am testing my index.js file by manual mocking these dependencies in **mocks** directory as follows:

```
__mocks__ 
    |_invokeApi
    |_decrypt
    |_cors
```

it says

```
FAIL  ./index.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Cannot find module '/opt/nodejs/kiwiCall' from 'index.js'

    However, Jest was able to find:
        '../../../../lambdas/Flights/Locations/index.js'

    You might want to include a file extension in your import, or update your 'moduleFileExtensions', which is currently ['js', 'json', 'jsx', 'ts', 'tsx', 'node'].

    See https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#modulefileextensions-array-string

      1 | "use strict";
      2 | 
    > 3 | const invokeApi = require("/opt/nodejs/kiwiCall");
```

Wanted to know how can I mock the dependencies of AWS lambda in inedx.test.js file

Comment: How do you mock these modules? Please provide the code

Comment: Hi, did you resolved this issue?

Answer (score 5):

In your package.json or jest.config you could add a moduleNameMapper for that directory.

```
  "jest": {
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "/opt/nodejs/(.*)": "<rootDir>/../nodejs/$1"
    },
  },
```

Comment: doesn't work for me,

My folder structure is similar:
lambdas
|_opt
   |_nodejs
      |_utils.js

mapping "/opt/nodejs/(.*)": "lambdas/opt/nodejs/$1" didn't work either.

Answer (score 3):

So I managed to figure out something based on my repository.

I'm using the moduleNameMapper to map the absolute path to another location in my repository to where I have the layer stored.

Eg.

```
moduleNameMapper: {'^/opt/config/config': '<rootDir>/src/layers/layers-core/config/config'}
```

In your case you could use a regex expression to match `/opt/nodejs/` and map it elsewhere. Hope that helped.

EDIT:

I completely changed my approach and used babel-plugin-module-resolver with babel-rewire. I did this because the above method was incompatible with rewire. It's quite easy setup and you just need to setup a babel alias within `.babelrc`.

eg.

```
{
  "plugins": [
    ["rewire"],
    ["babel-plugin-module-resolver", {
      "alias": {
        "/opt/config/config": "./src/layers/layers-core/config/config",
        "/opt/utils/util-logger": "./src/layers/layers-core/utils/util-logger",
        "/opt/slack": "./src/layers/layers-slack/slack"
      }
    }]
  ]
}
```

Combine this with IDE `jsconfig.json` path alias and you get full IDE support.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es2018",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "/opt/config/config": ["src/layers/layers-core/config/config"],
      "/opt/utils/util-logger": ["src/layers/layers-core/utils/util-logger"],
      "/opt/slack/*": ["src/layers/layers-slack/slack/*"],
    }
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist"]
}
```

You can then reference your layers with `jest.doMock('/opt/config/config', mockConfig);`

EDIT 2:
Found a way to get Jest to mock it. Just slip `{virtual: true}` into the mock!

`jest.doMock('/opt/config/config', mockConfig, {virtual: true});`

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the trick with `{virtual: true}`

Answer (score 2):

I have pretty much the same issue. I have defined a layer which contains common code that's shared between other functions in my project. My project structure looks something like this:

```
project/
  functions/
    function1/
      app.js
    function2/
      app.js
  shared/
    shared.js
```

I import my shared library like this:

```
const { doSomething } = require('/opt/shared');

exports.handler = async (event) => {
  const result = await doSomething();
  // etc...
  return {statusCode: 200};
}
```

This works when I deploy to AWS Lambda because the `/opt/shared` exists and it can be referenced correctly. It also works if I run this on my machine using `sam local invoke Function1` because it's running in a container, which makes `/opt/shared` available to the code.

However, I'm struggling to work out how I can mock this dependency in a unit test. If I simply do this: `jest.mock('/opt/shared')`, I'm getting: `Cannot find module '/opt/shared' from app.test.js`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the modulePaths option, from this [post](https://medium.com/dcms-blog/unit-testing-when-using-lambda-layers-bb906330b626).

[Documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#modulepaths-arraystring)

jest.config.js

```
"jest": {
  "modulePaths": [
      "<rootDir>/src/layers/base/nodejs/node_modules/"
  ]
}
```

You can dynamically create this array by scanning a directory

```
const testFolder = './functions/';
const fs = require('fs');
    
const modulePaths = fs.readdirSync(testFolder)
    .reduce((modulePaths, dirName) => {
        modulePaths.push(`functions/${dirName}/dependencies/nodejs/node_modules/`);
        return modulePaths;
    }, []);
```