# Test AWS lambdas and layer using Jest?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, jestjs

I have an AWS lambda API that uses a lambda `layer` with some helper functions.

Now, when deployed AWS forces a path for the layer that's something like `/opt/nodejs/lib/helpers/awsGatewayResponses`. However, locally I have another folder structure which (on my local machine) would make the path is `layers/api-layer/nodejs/lib/helpers/awsGatewayResponses`. (Cause I don't want to have a folder setup that `/opt/nodejs/lib/...`)

However, I'm setting up some tests using Jest and I've come across the issue that I have to change the imports which is of the format `/opt/nodejs/lib/helpers/...` to be `layers/api-layer/nodejs/lib/helpers/` otherwise I will get import errors - and I don't want to make this change since it is not aligned with the actual deployed environment.

I'm looking for something that can change my paths to be `layers/api-layer/nodejs/lib/helpers/` **only** when I'm running tests. Any ideas on how I can make some kind of dynamic import? I want to run some tests automatically on Github on commits.

Thanks in advance! Please let me know if I have to elaborate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unit test for aws lambda using jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60843904/unit-test-for-aws-lambda-using-jest)